# How to echo string with variable substitution in bash?

Tags: bash

I have a string like `${REPOSITORY}/company/api:${API_VERSION}`. `$REPOSITORY` and `$API_VERSION` are shell variables.

```
$ echo ${DATA_API_VERSION}
latest
$ echo ${REPOSITORY}
com.company.repo
```

I want to get the interpolated string that shows the values of these variables and assign it to another variable.

This is what I get:

```
$ echo "$image"
${REPOSITORY}/company/api:${API_VERSION}
```

I want this:

```
com.company.repo/company/api:latest
```

Comment: Check that you’re using double quotes: `image="${REPOSITORY}/company/api:${API_VERSION}"`. I reproduced your example and got the result you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sed` to search and replace the two variables.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

DATA_API_VERSION="latest"
REPOSITORY="com.company.repo"

image='${REPOSITORY}/company/api:${DATA_API_VERSION}'
sed -e "
    s/\${REPOSITORY}/$REPOSITORY/g
    s/\${DATA_API_VERSION}/$DATA_API_VERSION/g
" <<< "$image"
```

Comment: Note that this will have trouble if the variables contain slashes, newlines, or other special characters.